# evolution mapi for thunderbird

Tags: evolution, thunderbird, ms-exchange

1. Is there any plugin which can retrieve MS Exchange emails in Thunderbird just like evolution-mapi & evolution-exchange does for Evolution?
2. What happened If the server does not have IMAP enabled ?

Answer (score 4):

evolution-mapi uses the native Outlook protocol. There is no plugin for Thunderbird that does this on Linux.

evolution-exchange basically uses screen scraping of the Exchange web service. This only works with older versions of Exchange. There might be plugins that provide this kind of support for email in Thunderbird, but I haven't seen any yet.

At the moment, your best bet is to either have IMAP enabled on the server or to use evolution.

Comment: You would think Thunderbird would have implemented MAPI support, at least for just email support. I mean how many years has this been already?  I bet this has been on the wish lists for a decade.

Comment: The thunderbird developers don't seem to be particularly interested in this when I last talked about it with them.

Comment: I'm not surprised in the slightest, which is exactly my point.  The users want it, they've been asking for it for practically a decade, and all the excuses in the world don't scratch the truth.  They just aren't interested, and they were never truly interested.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for complete how to, AD address book, Calendar etc:

[howto-thunderbird-and-ms-exchange-server](http://www.high-on-it.co.za/2011/01/complete-how-to-setup-thunderbird-31x.html)

Comment: this is not what exactly wanted. Does half the job acutally. It tries to pick up an IMAP connection for the exchange server. If the server does not have IMAP enabled, mails will not flow in. The plugin in only for calendar and Address book.

Comment: Link is dead. This is the reason to post at least the essential stuff in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ExQuilla?

> ExQuilla is an addon for Mozilla's Thunderbird email client that
>   allows access to both messages and contacts stored on Exchange Server
>   2007 or 2010. ExQuilla uses EWS (Exchange Web Services) for access to
>   the server. ExQuilla is currently available in a beta version that
>   supports Thunderbird 15 - 17 on Windows, Linux, and OSX platforms.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/exquilla-exchange-web-services/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use **evolution-ews** it uses Exchange web services and is quick and I get my calendar and address book and is the best solution by far to get your Exchange services. This only works in Evolution.

**However** in the past I have used [Davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net), it uses Outlook Web Access to grab your mail and caldav to get your calendar, It spawns an IMAP+SMTP server on your system so any IMAP mail client can connect to it including Thunderbird. Its not to hard to setup just point it to your OWA url.